# Recommend a JSON-RPC library for java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, json-rpc

I'm looking around for a good solution for JSON-RPC either in JAVA and Javascript (both sides, but I don't mean it has to be the same project!).

Post your hints. I'd like a mainstream project with lot of examples around.

I've tried jsonrpc4j but I can't get it working with spring...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia have [list of JSON-RPC libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations) in various languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-json view to transfer data from client to server using JSON.
[spring-json view](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

on the official website you will find a list of JSON-RPC libraries/Clients for all languages including java and javascript

http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations